# Powershell script to detect log file failures

Tags: email, powershell

I run perfmon on a server and the log files go into a c:\perfmon folder. The perfmon task restarts each week and the log files just collect in there over time. There could be a range of csv file dates in that folder with different dates.

I would like to write a powershell script that will check that folder to make sure that there is a file there with todays modified date on it. If there isn't one for today I would like a FAILED email so that I know to look at perfmon for issues.

Has anyone written anything like this. I have tried several of the scripts in here and none do it exactly how I would like it to work. This is what I have so far based on other scripts.

It sort of works but it is checking all files and responding for all files as well. If I had 3 files over the last three days and none for today I would get 3 emails saying FAIL. If I have one for today and two older ones I get 3 OK emails. If I just have just one file for today I get one OK email. How do I restrict this to just one email for a fail or success. There could be 50-100 files in that folder after two years and I just want a FAIL if none of them are modified today.

Hope that all makes sense. I'm afraid my Powershell skills are very weak.

```
$EmailTech = @{
To = 'a@a.com'
SmtpServer = 'relayserver'
From = 'a@a.com'
}
$CompareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\perflogs\logs | ForEach-Object {
    $Files = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\perflogs\logs\*.csv | Where-Object {$_.LastWritetime -gt $CompareDate} | Measure-Object).Count
        if ($Files -eq 0) 
        {
        $EmailTech.Subject = 'Perfmon File ServerA - FAIL'
        $EmailTech.Body = 'A performance monitor log file was not found on ServerA for today'
        Send-MailMessage @EmailTech  
        }
        Else 
        {
        # If we found files it's ok and we don't report it
        $EmailTech.Subject = 'Perfmon File ServerA - OK'
        $EmailTech.Body = 'A performance monitor log file was found on ServerA for today'
        Send-MailMessage @EmailTech  
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this as a Windows Scheduled Task in the evening every day? Do you expect one e-mail after that run with `Success` or `Failed` based on the fact if there is a file in there with `ModifiedDate -eq today`?

Comment: Yes, once a day email from Task Schedule. Perfmon crashed on one of my servers and I didn't notice till I actually needed the csv file for a consultant. Sods law. All other 10 machines were fine, just the one he wanted.